# Can we Automate windows based application in AutoIT and integrate it in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, autoit

We have a huge application which is windows based(.Net), I know we can Automate and integrate some one click windows function in Selenium with the help of AutoIt But can we automate whole application with AutoIT and run it on Selenium ?
Or is not advisable to go for this option and use other tools such as UFT to automate web based applications ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium is a library which helps you to mimic user behavior in browser. If you want to automate windows desktop application, you don't need selenium in first place.

You might wanted to know whether one can use [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) with Java, instead of UFT/QTP for end to end testing of windows desktop based application. Yes, that's [possible](https://www.joecolantonio.com/2014/07/02/selenium-autoit-how-to-automate-non-browser-based-functionality/) but it would not be that easy.

Consider following points:-

1. QTP/UFT provides in built mechanism to identify object and add it to Object Repository, If you use AutoIT, you need to implement mechanism which will provide an easy way to change/modify object in case of change in object of AUT. Writing object properties directly in code does not make much sense. refer image-

[image]

2. QTP/UFT provides in built support for Excel and sending data as parameter. If you have to do this in Automation Framework, it will require framework designing skill.

There are lot advantages of QTP/UFT which I'm not enlisting here. But if you have choice and budget, I will suggest to go with QTP.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate response, Actually in my project they are already using UFT for automation but they wanted to switch it to Selenium,but as it's an end to end Windows application it would not be easy to automate whole application with AutoIt and integrate with Selenium as you have also suggested it won't be of any use and we can do it with help of other tools as well.

Comment: If it answers your question, then please consider to accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write what ever script you need with AutoIt and call it your preferred code bindings (C#, Java or whatever you write your selenium tests in) 
For example: [How to call a script from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622160/running-a-shell-script-from-java-code)