# Execute bash command within java program

Tags: java, linux, bash, process, command

It's been quite a while since I'm looking for but I don't find the solution. I'm trying to execute bash command on Linux within .jar file. 
For that, I tried many things, including this :

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "M1_MIAGE_PDL_VIZ_GROUPE3.jar", "menu").start();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh -c java -jar M1_MIAGE_PDL_VIZ_GROUPE3.jar menu");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh -c", "java -jar M1_MIAGE_PDL_VIZ_GROUPE3.jar menu"});
```

So, when I click on the .jar file, I would like to that the program open a bash, and execute the command (java -jar ...), to execute another part of the program.

Any ideas as to how to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand this, you first need to understand how you would run that command at a shell prompt.

```
$ sh -c "java -jar M1_MIAGE_PDL_VIZ_GROUPE3.jar menu"
```

Note where the double quotes are.  The first argument is `-c`.  The second argument is the stuff inside the quotes; i.e. `java -jar M1_MIAGE_PDL_VIZ_GROUPE3.jar menu`

Now we translate that into Java:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder(
   "/bin/sh", 
   "-c", 
   "java -jar M1_MIAGE_PDL_VIZ_GROUPE3.jar menu").start();
```

Having said that, the above doesn't actually achieve anything.  Certainly, it doesn't open a fresh console window to display the console output etcetera.  Unlike Windows "CMD.exe", UNIX / Linux shells do not provide console / terminal functionality.  For that you need to use a "terminal" application.

For example, if you are using GNOME

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder(
   "gnome-terminal", 
   "-e", 
   "java -jar M1_MIAGE_PDL_VIZ_GROUPE3.jar menu").start();
```

will (probably) do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i still have a problem. I see the gnome-terminal opening, but it close directly after. I'm tried to insert a waitFor() method after calling the process, but didn't work.

Comment: Try adding "; sleep 60" at the end of "java ..." command string.  Alternatively, see if one of the (many) alternative terminal emulators has an option to not exit immediately.

Comment: The problem is that when I open a terminal, it opens in the /home/user directory. I will insert the absolute path after the java -jar command and the program will work fine. Thank you for you help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to create a shell script (.sh extension) and then you can easily run that from within the Java program.
There is a good answer on a previous question on how to run shell scripts within Java [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622160/running-a-shell-script-from-java-code).

To create a shell script you can use any text editor and create a file with the extension .sh and just enter the lines as you would in the bash terminal.